# placing a formula at the right side of the graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

I'm having trouble with centering the formula for function f on the following picture:

```
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
\draw[line width=0.8pt][->] (-3.5,0)--(3.5,0);
\draw[line width=0.8pt][->] (0,-3)--(0,3);
\draw[line width=0.7pt][color=red] (-3,-1)--(0,-1);
\draw[line width=0.7pt][color=red] (0,1)--(3,1);
\draw[red] (0,1) circle(3pt);
\draw[red] (0,-1) circle(3pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
&{\hspace{1cm}}&
f(x)
\ =\
\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
-1 & \text{for }x<0
\\[0.5ex]
1 & \text{for }x>0
\end{array}
\right.
\end{array}
$$
```

Here is the result:

[image]

I would like to have the formula in the middle, i.e. placed as the horizontal axis on the graph, not at the bottom.

Comment: welcome to the site -- something like the answer below -- please see if it meets the requirement

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228). 
Otherwise, more specifically about your question: You can try with `\vspace`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx, tikz, array}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
            \draw[line width=0.8pt][->] (-3.5,0)--(3.5,0)coordinate(aux);
            \draw[line width=0.8pt][->] (0,-3)--(0,3);
            \draw[line width=0.7pt][color=red] (-3,-1)--(0,-1);
            \draw[line width=0.7pt][color=red] (0,1)--(3,1);
            \draw[red] (0,1) circle(3pt);
            \draw[red] (0,-1) circle(3pt);
            \node[right=1cm of aux]{
            f(x)
            \ =\
                    \left\{
                    \begin{array}{cl}
                        -1 & \text{for }x<0
                        \\[0.5ex]
                        1 & \text{for }x>0
                    \end{array}
                    \right.
                \end{array} 
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: yes, that is what I was looking for. Thanks very much to both of you. sadly, I don't have enough points to upvote the replies :(

Answer (score 4):

<del>Two</del> Three possibilities (thanks to @BlackMild for proposing another option):

- Use the `baseline` option of the `tikzpicture` and add the formula outside. The baseline will determine the vertical position of the `tikzpicture` relative to other TeX boxes (like the consitutents of the formula) on the same line.
- Put the figure into a `local bounding box` and place the formula beside this box as a separate node. The placement of the two nodes is controlled by TikZ means.
- Make the formula part of the figure by placing it at the appropriate coordinate as a separate TikZ node.

Visually, there is not much difference in this example as both, the picture and the formula, are vertically symmetric.

**TikZ option `baseline`**

Note that the base line of `f(x)` is aligned with the horizontal axis, as we have declared the origin as the base line of the figure.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,baseline={(0,0)}]
\draw[line width=0.8pt][->] (-3.5,0)--(3.5,0);
\draw[line width=0.8pt][->] (0,-3)--(0,3);
\draw[line width=0.7pt][red] (-3,-1)--(0,-1);
\draw[line width=0.7pt][red,fill=white] (0,1)--(3,1);
\draw[red,fill=white] (0,1) circle(3pt);
\draw[red,fill=white] (0,-1) circle(3pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\qquad
\(f(x) = \begin{cases}
         -1 & \text{for $x<0$}\\[0.5ex]
          1 & \text{for $x>0$}
       \end{cases}
\)
\end{document}
```

**TikZ option `local bounding box`**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[scale=0.6,local bounding box=L]
    \draw[line width=0.8pt][->] (-3.5,0)--(3.5,0);
    \draw[line width=0.8pt][->] (0,-3)--(0,3);
    \draw[line width=0.7pt][red] (-3,-1)--(0,-1);
    \draw[line width=0.7pt][red] (0,1)--(3,1);
    \draw[red,fill=white] (0,1) circle(3pt);
    \draw[red,fill=white] (0,-1) circle(3pt);
  \end{scope}
  \node[right=2em of L]
    {\(f(x) = \begin{cases}
         -1 & \text{for $x<0$}\\[0.5ex]
          1 & \text{for $x>0$}
       \end{cases}
    \)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Formula positioned inside the figure**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
  \draw[line width=0.8pt][->] (-3.5,0)--(3.5,0) node[right=2em]
    {\(f(x) = \begin{cases}
         -1 & \text{for $x<0$}\\[0.5ex]
          1 & \text{for $x>0$}
       \end{cases}
    \)};
  \draw[line width=0.8pt][->] (0,-3)--(0,3);
  \draw[line width=0.7pt][red] (-3,-1)--(0,-1);
  \draw[line width=0.7pt][red] (0,1)--(3,1);
  \draw[red,fill=white] (0,1) circle(3pt);
  \draw[red,fill=white] (0,-1) circle(3pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using 'local bounding box' for the figure of graph is another way

Comment: @BlackMild Interesting suggestion, I'd like to add it, but I fail to see how this could help.

Comment: please check this `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[scale=0.6,local bounding box=L]
\draw[->] (-3.5,0)--(3.5,0); 
\draw[->] (0,-2)--(0,2);
\draw[red] (-3,-1)--(0,-1) (0,1)--(3,1);
\draw[red,fill=white] 
(0,1) circle(3pt) (0,-1) circle(3pt);
\end{scope}
\path (L.east)+(1,0) node[right]
{\(f(x) = \begin{cases}
  -1 & \text{for $x<0$}\\[0.5ex]
  1 & \text{for $x>0$}
 \end{cases}
\)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}`

Comment: @BlackMild Thanks for your contribution (including `fill=white`).

Comment: You are welcome! just check several good answers from you in other posts, and learn something useful